# eval() with variables from an object in the scope

Tags: javascript, eval

how can I execute a string as code (using `eval()`) and give it some variables? For example, I've got an object named `vars` and want each of its properties to be accessible for the code without exciplitely specifying the objects name. Something like this:

```
function evalWithVariables(func, vars) {
 //some magic here
 return eval(func);
}

function test() {
 var retval = evalWithVariables("a>5", {"a":7});
 console.log(retval);
}
```

Oh, and the code is trusted, it comes from the same server as the script, it is not user-generated and I'm pretty sure that `eval` is the right tool here (and I know that `eval` is often evil).

**Edit:** The most important thing for me is that the code that gets passed to `eval()` looks good, is short and doesn't have to contain helper variable names or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discovered that it's possible to just use `with`:

```
eval("with (vars) {var result = (" + func + ")}");
```

Comment: Note that with() is not allowed in strict mode

Answer (score 2):

You can reconstitute the values as JavaScript code and prepend it the code to be executed. Then, assign the result of the actual expression to a local variable. So,

```
evalWithVariables("a>5", {"a":7});
```

actually `eval`s:

```
var a=7; var result = (a>5);
```

Then, right after the `eval`, check the value of `result`:

```
function evalWithVariables(func, vars) {
 var varString = "";

 for (var i in vars)
     varString += "var " + i + " = " + vars[i] + ";";   

 eval(varString + "; var result = (" + func + ")");
 return result;
}
```

Comment: The concept itself is unclean :)

Answer (score 1):

An option to forgo `eval()` is to generate a function and then use `with()`, as you did, to change the block scope:

```
function evalWithVariables(func, vars) {
    return new Function("v", "with (v) { return (" + func +")}")(vars);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just more complicated and slower than my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use a more functional approach:

```
function evalWithVariables(func, vars) {
    return func(vars);
}
evalWithVariables(function(vars) { return vars.a > 5; }, {"a":7})
```

Or shorter:

```
(function(vars) { return vars.a > 5; })({"a":7})
```