# How to pass multiple variables into an "eval" expression using "with"?

Tags: javascript, eval

I am trying to accomplish something like in : [eval() with variables from an object in the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359639/eval-with-variables-from-an-object-in-the-scope)

The correct answers suggests using the "with" keyword, but I can't find any examples of someone actually using "with". Can someone explain how to pass multiple variables using "with" into an "eval" expression like in the link above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wouldn't recommend using *with* or *eval* except as a learning exercise because either one slows code down, and using them both at once is especially bad and frowned upon by the larger js community.

but it does work:

```
function evalWithVariables(code) {
  var scopes=[].slice.call(arguments,1), // an array of all object passed as variables
  A=[], // and array of formal parameter names for our temp function
  block=scopes.map(function(a,i){ // loop through the passed scope objects
        var k="_"+i;  // make a formal parameter name with the current position
        A[i]=k;  // add the formal parameter to the array of formal params
        return "with("+k+"){"   // return a string that call with on the new formal parameter
  }).join(""), // turn all the with statements into one block to sit in front of _code_
  bonus=/\breturn/.test(code) ? "": "return "; // if no return, prepend one in
   // make a new function with the formal parameter list, the bonus, the orig code, and some with closers
  // then apply the dynamic function to the passed data and return the result
  return Function(A, block+bonus+code+Array(scopes.length+1).join("}")).apply(this, scopes);  
}

evalWithVariables("a+b", {a:7}, {b:5}); // 12
evalWithVariables("(a+b*c) +' :: '+ title ", {a:7}, {b:5}, {c:10}, document);
// == "57 :: javascript - How to pass multiple variables into an "eval" expression using "with"? - Stack Overflow"
```

edited to use any number of scope sources, watch out for property name conflicts.
again, i don't normally use *with*, but this was kinda fun...

Comment: what do you mean by "slow". Using "with" or using "with" with "eval" ?Also, your example passes just one variable. How do you pass multiple ones?

Comment: @John: by slow i mean the login you pass in as a string in this fashion executes much more slowly than if you used something like o1.a+o2.b instead. the reason _with_ slows down code is due to more expensive lookup, and _eval_ prevent a lot of compiler optimizations.

Comment: But that won't work if you don't know the number of vars until run time. You would actually have to create the function on the fly from a string and then do multiple evals then!

Comment: As @dandavis said, using `with` is not recommended. Here's why - http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Comment: @John: edited to allow any number of objects as lexical name sources.

Comment: I guess I had no idea how complicated a question I was asking. I thought you could just "pass" in the variables like an array or something. I appreciate your answer. Can you comment it ? Its hard to read and understand.

Comment: @John: i added a comment per line explaining what each segment does.